# React Native: state is null sometimes - setState is working asynchronously

Tags: reactjs, react-native, null, state, setstate

I think I do have some problems with the state of my application . I already figured out that `this.setState({ ... })` is a function which is working asynchronously.. So, I think this has something to do with my problem.

My problem is that I want to show a dialog popup to my user when I am sending a push notification via OneSignal. This push notification gets received by both iOS and Android. Even when the app is running in the 
background, foreground or got killed and isn't even running in the background. For the popup dialog I am using this package: [react-native-popup-dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popup-dialog)

This popup is only visible if I send certain key/value pairs with the push notification. These keys are:

1. `showPopup`:`true` - Displaying the popup when true. If it isn't set or not equals true, it isn't displayed!
2. `openLink`:`mydomain.de`- Adds a button with a link to the popup
3. `buttonText`:`Open in Browser` - Sets the button text to the link

> Note, the extra URL button is only added to the popup if key `openLink` and `buttonText` is set. Of none of them or only one of the key is set, it isn't displaying this button.

However, the popup dialog only shows up sometimes in some cases. I will list them for you below:

1. Case 1: The application is opened. In this case the popup shows up on iOS and Android. This gets handled by the 
   `onReceived` function!
2. Case 2: The app is completely close (swiped off the screen/killed). In this case, the popup shows up on Android
   devices but not on iOS devices! This gets handled by the `onOpened` function!
3. Case 3: The app has been opened and is now running in the background. In this case, the popup shows up on iOS
   devices but not on Android devices. This gets handled by the `onOpened` function too!

So, cause I am not getting and error messages or something else, I guess I am right with my guess that this issue is 
due the asynchronous `this.setState({ ... })` function.

My question now is how can I make sure that the state of `notification` and `visible` is always set before rendering the `getPopup(...)` method.. I already was thinking about implementing it so that I call the `getPopup(...)` function with parameters. So, I can be sure the parameters are always set before calling the method. However, sadly this is not possible. Cause the class you see below, the `SuperScreen` class, is just a class which gets extended by some subclasses to bundle my code like the push notification code or some functions I need in every of these subclasses.

Also, I already tried out to add a variable to my `SuperClass` state e.g. called `stateSet` which gets set after the `setState({ ... })` function of either `onReceived` or `onOpened` has finished and verify it with 
 `if(this.state.stateSet)` in the first line of the `getPopup(...)` function. However, this is also not possible.  The reason for that is because then my popup is not closing anymore when I am pressing either `Ok` or the link button.

If you guys have any ideas on how to solve this problem I really would appreciate it!
Here is my code:

```
export default class SuperScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pushNotification: null,
      visible: false
    };

    OneSignal.init("00000000", {
      kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: true
    });

    OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(0);
    OneSignal.enableVibrate(true);
    OneSignal.enableSound(true);

    OneSignal.addEventListener("received", this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener("opened", this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener("ids", this.onIds);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    OneSignal.removeEventListener("received", this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener("opened", this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener("ids", this.onIds);
  }

  onReceived = notification => {
    //App is opened!
    console.log("Notification received: ", notification);

    this.setState({
      pushNotification: notification,
      visible: true
    });

    if (notification.payload.notificationID != null) {
      firebase.analytics().logEvent("Popup_Link_Button", {
        notificationID: notification.payload.notificationID,
        clicked: true
      });
    }
  };

  onOpened = openResult => {
    //App either is closed or running in background
    //Android:  Closed: Showing       Background: Not Showing
    //iOS:      Closed: Not Showing   Background: Showing)

    console.log("openResult: ", openResult);

    this.setState({
      pushNotification: openResult.notification,
      visible: true
    });

    if (openResult.notification.payload.notificationID != null) {
      firebase.analytics().logEvent("Popup_Link_Button", {
        notificationID: openResult.notification.payload.notificationID,
        clicked: true
      });
    }
  };

  onIds = device => {
    console.log("Device info: ", device);
  };

  getPopup() {
    if (
      this.state.pushNotification != null &&
      this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData != null &&
      this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData.showPopup != null &&
      this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData.showPopup == "true"
    ) {
      var actionButtons = null;

      if (
        this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData.openLink != null &&
        this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData.buttonText != null
      ) {
        actionButtons = [
          <DialogButton
            text="Ok"
            key={0}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({ visible: false });
              firebase.analytics().logEvent("Popup_Link_Button", {
                notificationID: this.state.pushNotification.payload
                  .notificationID,
                opened: false
              });
            }}
          />
        ];

        actionButtons.push(
          <DialogButton
            text={this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData.buttonText}
            key={1}
            onPress={() => {
              this.openLink(
                this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData.openLink
              );
              this.setState({ visible: false });
              firebase.analytics().logEvent("Popup_Link_Button", {
                notificationID: this.state.pushNotification.payload
                  .notificationID,
                link: this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData
                  .openLink,
                opened: true
              });
            }}
          />
        );
      } else {
        actionButtons = [
          <DialogButton
            text="Ok"
            key={0}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({ visible: false });
              firebase.analytics().logEvent("Popup_Link_Button", {
                popupID: this.state.pushNotification.payload.notificationID,
                opened: false
              });
            }}
          />
        ];
      }

      return (
        <Dialog
          visible={this.state.visible}
          dialogTitle={
            <DialogTitle
              title={
                this.state.pushNotification == null
                  ? ""
                  : this.state.pushNotification.payload.title
              }
            />
          }
          dialogAnimation={
            new SlideAnimation({
              slideFrom: "bottom"
            })
          }
          dialogStyle={{ marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20 }}
          actions={actionButtons}
        >
          <DialogContent>
            <Text />
            <Text>
              {this.state.pushNotification == null
                ? ""
                : this.state.pushNotification.payload.body}
            </Text>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Posted code is bulky enough, yet it lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There's no stateSet you mentioned. getPopup is not used. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem. A demo that can be debugged like Stackblitz would help. If the problem is async state then the case is likely not specific to Native, so components could be stubbed.

Comment: It is more or less not possible to replicate my problem cause you cannot recieve push notification here on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

you can add a callback to setState to ensure the code runs after setting the state:

```
this.setState().then({ //Do something here. })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `async`, `await` for asynchronously .

```js
onReceived = async (notification) => {
    //App is opened!
    console.log("Notification received: ", notification);

    await this.setState({ // It will wait until finish setState. 
      pushNotification: notification,
      visible: true
    }); 

    if (notification.payload.notificationID != null) {
      firebase.analytics().logEvent("Popup_Link_Button", {
        notificationID: notification.payload.notificationID,
        clicked: true
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: When I make those function working asynchronously my push notifications don't get received...!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback in setState!, i learned from it a month ago and it's been useful since . Check [this article](https://medium.com/@voonminghann/when-to-use-callback-function-of-setstate-in-react-37fff67e5a6c) , you can pass a function as a callback ;)

```
this.setState(
    { pushNotification: notification,
      visible: true }, () => {this.getPopup()}) //this.getPopup it's the second parameter, a callback
```

Check the article, it's short and will help

Comment: But the problem is, as already described, the function `getPopup(...)` get's only called from the subclasses..

Comment: A workaround would be to tell the subclass to fire the render method once again for example so the subclass calls the `getPopup(...)` method.. but I don't know if this is possible..